# How do I list the custom EventGrid topics in a resource group in C# for azure?

Tags: c#, azure

Via the cli, you can run this:

```
az eventgrid topic list -g resource-group-name
```

I've been digging through the [Azure C# SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/), but I can't find any way to do this via C#?

What's the C# equivalent of the above code?

For example, for listing resource groups, it would be:

```
IAzure azure = ...;
var resourceGroups = azure.ResourceGroups.List();
```

How do I do that for EventGrid topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get an EventGridManagementClient from an IAzure interface?

The [feature of Event Grid service is coming soon](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#feature-availability-and-road-map) with Azure Management Libraries for .NET. So you could not get an `EventGridManagementClient` from an `IAzure` interface.

You could use [`ListByResourceGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.eventgrid.topicsoperationsextensions.listbyresourcegroupasync?view=azure-dotnet) as Sajeetharan provided.

Also there is [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/topics/listbyresourcegroup) that list all the topics under a resource group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`ListByResourceGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.eventgrid.topicsoperationsextensions.listbyresourcegroupasync?view=azure-dotnet) below,

```
 IPage<Topic> topicsInResourceGroupPage = this.EventGridManagementClient.Topics.ListByResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroup).Result;
```

[`Complete Code`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3c92879d86272035c50693e179af36527f2312b1/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid/tests/Tests/ScenarioTests.TopicTests.CRUD.cs)

Comment: How do I get an `EventGridManagementClient` from an `IAzure` interface?

Comment: What complete source code? The example you linked to simply uses `this.EventGridManagementClient`, which is initialized in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3c92879d86272035c50693e179af36527f2312b1/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid/tests/Tests/ScenarioTests.cs via a `MockContext`, which is totally unhelpful to me.

Comment: Sorry i have attached a wrong url https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/dc23a39caf37d07f02512540d20c29866ff83759/sdk/eventgrid/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid/src/Generated/TopicsOperationsExtensions.cs